# cordova gradle 6.0.1 error "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1"

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to locally build my Android app using cordova. I've downloaded the most recent gradle version but on exporting I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :
```

Here is the build.gradle buildscript:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.0.1'
}
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` also states `distributionUrl` is set to `http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't confuse [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/release-notes.html) with the [Android gradle pluing](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).

The pluing `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1'` **doesn't** exist.
The latest **stable** version of the plugin is: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2`.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. Could you advise me on the latest safe classpath to use?

Comment: @James Updated the answer. Here you can find all the [info](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin).